# R Markdown cannot get RStudio Version - error message in knit

Tags: r, rstudio, markdown, version, kint

I have the following line in my R Markdown code chunk 
       `RStudio.Version()$version`

when I run the knit on the R Markdown to create a Word document, I get the following error message:

> Error in RStudio.Version(): could not find function "RStudio.Version"

When I run this function `RStudio.Version()`  in RStudio console, I get the version and the function runs, but not with knit when I run R Markdown.

Anyone has an advice or solution?

Comment: As far as I know, that function doesn't exist anywhere. If you are looking for the version of your IDE, you can have it returned with `rstudioapi::versionInfo()`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replicate your issue running `RStudio.Version()` while knitting. As Phil suggests, `rstudioapi::versionInfo()` seems the best alternative while knitting.

Comment: Some addition clarity on why RStudio.Version() fails https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/6892